# XSLT substring-after

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have string:  `$number=Twentyone one two three`. I need to fetch the value after the string `one` that is `two three`. I have written the below xslt query:

```
substring-after($number,'one')
```

which returns `one two three`.

What is the the query to exactly match the whole string only with `one` and then return `two three`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor like the question is tagged), you should be able to do this easier with `replace()`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace($number,'^.*one(.*)$','$1'))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $vS in 'Twentyone one two three'
       return
         codepoints-to-string(
            reverse(
                string-to-codepoints(
                      substring-before(
                           codepoints-to-string(
                                 reverse(string-to-codepoints($vS))
                                                ), 
                           'eno')
                                     )
                    )
                               )
```

**when evaluated produces the string**:

" `two three`"

---

**Explanation**:

The problem is to find the substring after the *last* occurrence of the string "one" in the original string.

One solution is to find the substring before the string "eno" (the reverse of "one") in the reversed original string -- then reverse the result.

In XPath 2.0 there is a standard function `reverse()` that produces from a sequence another one, which is the reversed original sequence. There is also a standard XPath 2.0 function `string-to-codepoints()` that from a string produces a sequence of the codepoints (think Unicode "character-codes") that comprise this string. Conversely, the standard XPath 2.0 function `codepoints-to-string()` takes a sequence of valid Unicode codepoints (integers) and produces the string that is comprised of these codepoints.

Therefore, an XPath 2.0 expression that produces the reverse of a string `$vS` is:

```
codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-codepoints($vS)))
```

Using this knowledge we can construct the XPath 2.0 expression above, that provides the wanted solution.

**Even more generally**:

To find the substring of `$vS` after the last occurrence of `$vS2` in it, use this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
 codepoints-to-string(
    reverse(
        string-to-codepoints(
              substring-before(
                   codepoints-to-string(
                         reverse(string-to-codepoints($vS))
                                     ), 
                   codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-codepoints($vS2))))
                             )
            )
                       )
```

---

**II. Alternative solution** -- if just needing the words after the last occurrence of a string

If you only need the sequence of trailing words after the last occurrence of the particular string ("one") -- without the exact separators, you can use this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
for $vS in 'Twentyone one two three'
   return
     tokenize($vS, '\W')[position() > index-of(tokenize($vS, '\W'), 'one')[last()]]
```

In case you need not the sequence of trailing words, but their concatenation (using a standard delimiter, such as a space), use:

```
for $vS in 'Twentyone one two three'
   return
     string-join(
       tokenize($vS, '\W')[position() > index-of(tokenize($vS, '\W'), 'one')[last()]],
       ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how much you know about the input string. If you know in advance that it contains `$number=Twentyone one two three`, then you already know that the answer is `two three` so you don't need to do any matching. But presumably you don't know that. But you must know something about it, and we can't solve the problem without knowing what. Dimitre has assumed that you want the string after the last occurrence of "one" in the input, but I can't see anything in your question to justify that inference. What would you want if the input was "twenty-one bones"? You might (for all we know) be looking for the string after the first occurrence of "one" that is surrounded by spaces. Or for the string that follows first word that is the English name of a single-digit number, or for the string after the first word that is three characters long. We simply don't know, and you can't expect us to guess.